# How do I deterministically convert Pandas string columns into specific numbers?

Tags: python, pandas

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75966231/how-do-i-convert-a-pandas-string-column-into-specific-numbers-without-using-a-lo/75966283#75966283) and was grateful for the community's help.

I have a problem wherein I want to convert the dataframe strings into numbers. This time I cannot manually map the strings to numbers as this column is quite long in practise (the example below is just a minimal example). The constraint is that every time the same string is repeated, the number should be the same.

I tried using `pd.to_numeric` but it gave me an error -

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['mechanical@engineer', 'Works on machines'], ['field engineer', 'Works on pumps'],
        ['lab_scientist', 'Publishes papers'], ['field engineer', 'Works on pumps'],
        ['lab_scientist','Publishes papers']]# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Job1', 'Description'])
role_to_code = {"mechanical@engineer": 0, "field engineer": 1, "lab_scientist": 2}

df['Job1'] = df['Job1'].map(role_to_code)

print(df.head())

df['Description'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Description'])
```

Here is the error -

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "Works on machines" at position 0
```

The solution for the above error as per similar SO posts is to specify a separator. But as the dataset is quite big, I don't want to specify multiple separators. Is there a way to automate this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, there is a pandas *builtin* to do that : [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html).

> `pandas.factorize`(values, sort=False, use_na_sentinel=True,
> size_hint=None)
>      *Encode the object as an enumerated type or categorical variable.*
>
> This method is useful for obtaining a **numeric representation of an
> array** when all that matters is **identifying distinct values.**

```
df["Description_new"] = pd.factorize(df['Description'])[0]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   Job1        Description  Description_new
0     0  Works on machines                0
1     1     Works on pumps                1
2     2   Publishes papers                2
3     1     Works on pumps                1
4     2   Publishes papers                2
```